# Create SQL Function/Procedure from 3 Tables

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

I have 3 tables, category, Resource Human and HR Plan.

[image]

I want to calculate The amount Group by Category

I created this SQL query:

```
select 
    CostCategory.CostCategory, sum(isnull(HRPplan.Amount, 0))
from 
    CostCategory
left join 
    HRPplan on HRPplan.Month between 1 and 3 
            and HRPplan.Year = 2019 
            and HRPplan.IDRPH in (select HumanResource.IDRPH 
                                  from HumanResource
                                  where HumanResource.IDCostCategory = CostCategory.IDCostegory)
group by  
    CostCategory.CostCategory
```

and it returns a result, but I have another 2 tables exactly look like Human Resource & HPlan, to use it to calculate the amount, so if I use the same code mentioned above the query performance not good. And I don't how to use the function/procedure in SQL, since that the year & the month will be inserted as parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the DDL and sample data DML in the questions makes it easier for providing a quick solution. Also, columns used in your Query does not fully resemble with your provided screenshot, so I am providing these approaches based on the screenshot provided.

Prepared DDL and test data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CostCategory;
GO

CREATE TABLE CostCategory
(
    IDCostCategory  INT
    ,CostCategory   VARCHAR(10)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT INTO CostCategory
VALUES
(1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'C')
GO


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS HumanResource;
GO

CREATE TABLE HumanResource
(
    IDHR            INT
    ,IDCostCategory INT
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT INTO HumanResource
VALUES
(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 2)
GO



DROP TABLE IF EXISTS HRPlan;
GO

CREATE TABLE HRPlan
(
    IDHRPlan        INT
    ,IDHR           INT
    ,Amount         INT
    ,Month          INT
    ,Year           INT
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT INTO HRPlan
VALUES
    (1, 1, 10 , 1, 2019)
,   (2, 1, 12 , 2, 2019)
,   (3, 1, 15 , 2, 2019)
,   (4, 2, 50 , 1, 2019)
,   (5, 2, 0 , 2, 2019)
,   (6, 2, 100 , 3, 2019)
,   (4, 3, 40 , 1, 2019)
,   (5, 3, 50 , 2, 2019)
,   (6, 3, 30 , 3, 2019)
GO
```

For tracking performance you can set IO and Time statistics ON:

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
```

**Solution 1**: Using Outer Apply (Better performance than solution#2 below)

```
SELECT  CC.CostCategory, ISNULL(OA.Amount, 0)
FROM    CostCategory CC
        OUTER APPLY (
                        SELECT  Amount = SUM(ISNULL(HP.Amount, 0))
                        FROM    HRPlan HP
                        WHERE   HP.Month BETWEEN 1 AND 3
                        AND     HP.Year = 2019  
                        AND     EXISTS  (
                                            SELECT  1
                                            FROM    HumanResource HR
                                            WHERE   HR.IDCostCategory = CC.IDCostCategory
                                            AND     HR.IDHR = HP.IDHR
                                        )
                    ) OA;
```

**Solution 2:** Using Left join

```
SELECT  CC.CostCategory, ISNULL(SUM(HP.Amount), 0)
FROM    CostCategory CC
        LEFT JOIN HumanResource HR
            ON  CC.IDCostCategory = HR.IDCostCategory
        LEFT JOIN HRPlan HP
            ON HR.IDHR = HP.IDHR
            AND HP.Month BETWEEN 1 AND 3
            AND HP.Year = 2019
GROUP   BY CC.CostCategory;
```

**Note**:- You can think about creating columnstore index on HRPlan table and create Rowstore/Columnstore index on the other 2 tables which covers the joins and selected columns for getting far better performance.

Comment: thank you very much, the 1st solution was the best one, event that I calculate the amount of 4 columns.

Comment: just an info, in solution 1, you need to add "GROUP   BY CC.CostCategory" after "OA"

Comment: @MedAmin, no you don't. If you add GROUP BY there, the query will throw error as no aggregation is done on the outer query. Aggregation is being done in the OUTER APPLY part of the query. If you have duplicates in CostCategory table, you rather have to use a DISTINCT in the query.

Comment: Column 'cost_category.CostCategory' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. so this is the error, I need to use GROUP BY to show results.

Comment: @MedAmin, 1> Please go here and run the same in SQL Server: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d5627/2

Comment: @MedAmin 2> The above solution is with respect to the given problem. If you have more columns or the actual query you are trying to write is different or you are trying to do some additional Aggregation, the query have to be changed accordingly. Please post a separate question in StackOverflow if your requirement is different from the one posted here. 3> Once you have used an alias for a table name, you need to use the alias name for referring the column in your select (in case that is your issue)

Answer (score 1):

for improve performance you could avoid the in clause

```
select CostCategory.CostCategory, sum(isnull(HRPplan.Amount,0))
from CostCategory
left join HRPplan on HRPplan.Month between 1 and 3  and HRPplan.Year = 2019 
LEFT JOIN HumanResource ON HumanResource.IDCostCategory = CostCategory.IDCostegory
  and umanResource.IDRPH  = HRPplan.IDRPH 
group by CostCategory.CostCategory
```

Comment: it will show just records with values, and I wan to show all the records even with 0 amount

Comment: I do not think this query would give what is being asked. The join orders need to be changed. You can take a look at the 2 solutions I have provided below and let me know.